# Scala type system : basic type mismatch

Tags: scala, type-parameter

I have a basic type system type mismatch problem:
I have a class with a method

```
def Create(nodeItem : NodeItem) = {p_nodeStart.addEndNode(nodeItem)}
```

where p_nodeStart is NodeCache

```
class NodeCache[END_T<:BaseNode] private(node: Node) extends BaseNode {
def addEndNode(endNode : END_T) = {this.CACHE_HAS_ENDNODES.Create(endNode)}
```

and the error its giving me is:

```
error: type mismatch;
found   : nodes.NodeItem
required: Nothing
    def Create(nodeItem : NodeItem) = {p_nodeStart.addEndNode(nodeItem)}
```

while the NodeCache is defined as

```
object NodeTrigger {
def Create() {
val nodeTimeCache         = NodeCache.Create[NodeItem](node)
```

and in object NodeCache

```
object NodeCache {
def Create[END_T<:BaseNode]() {
val nodeCache = new NodeCache[END_T](node);
```

Any ideas, how to fix the error?

Comment: Please add the "^" pointing to the exact place of the error.

Answer (score 1):

> where p_nodeStart is NodeCache

NodeCache-what? NodeCache is parameterized, and it looks like p_nodeStart is NodeCache[Nothing]. How was it defined?